# Theorem 3.11 (c): Rudin's PMA

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I wanted to ask some clarification on one of the proofs in Rudin's PMA, specifically Theorem 3.11 (c). It states that

> In $\mathbb R^k$, every Cauchy sequence converges.

The proof for it is as follows:

> Let $\{\mathbf x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R^k$. Define $E_N$ to be the set $\mathbf x_N, \mathbf x_{N + 1}, \ldots$. **Then for some $N$, we have that the diameter of $E_N$ is less than 1.** The range of $\{\mathbf x_n\}$ is the union of $E_N$ and the finite set $\{\mathbf x_1, \mathbf x_2, \ldots, \mathbf x_{N - 1}\}$. Then $\{\mathbf x_n\}$ is bounded. Since every bounded subset of $\mathbb R^k$ has compact closure in $\mathbb R^k$ by Theorem 2.41, then (c) follows from (b).

In the bolded part, I have no clue as to how we can just say that there exists some N. Is there some property of Cauchy sequences that I'm missing?

Comment: Take $\varepsilon = 1$ in the definition.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I think you have to take an  $\epsilon <1$.

Comment: @geetha290krm You're right given Rudin's phrase _less than $1$_, though he might equally well have written _at most_ $1$ since the aim here is merely to show a Cauchy sequence is bounded. :)

Comment: After the definition 3.9, Rudin states that a sequence $\left\lbrace p_n\right\rbrace$ is a Cauchy sequence iff $\displaystyle\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \text{diam } E_N =0$, where $E_N=\left\lbrace p_N, p_{N+1}, p_{N+2}, \ldots\right\rbrace$. Therefore, given a Cauchy sequence, there exists some $N$ for which $\text{diam } E_N < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy, by the definition of Cauchy sequence, exists $N$ s.t. $m,n>N\Rightarrow {\rm d}(x_m,x_n)<\frac{1}{2}$. We claim the set $E_{N+1}=\{x_{N+1}, x_{N+2},\cdots\}$ has diameter less than $1$. In fact take arbitrary $a,b\in E_{N+1}$. Say $a=x_m, b=x_n (m,n>N)$. Then ${\rm d}(a,b)={\rm d}(x_m,x_n)<\frac{1}{2}$
\begin{equation*}
\Rightarrow {\rm diam}E_{N+1}:=\sup_{a,b\in E_{N+1}}{\rm d}(a,b)\le \frac{1}{2}<1.
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

Think about how, after a certain N, you can make any two n > N members of the Cauchy sequence arbitrarily close together.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).